# Keras with TF backend: get gradient of outputs with respect to inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a very simple Keras MLP, and I'm trying to get the gradient of the outputs with respect to the inputs.

I'm using the following code:

```py
regressor = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(n_features,), activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
])
regressor.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.1), loss='mse')

regressor.fit(x, y)

output_tens = regressor.layers[-1].output
input_tens = regressor.layers[0].input

grad = tf.gradients(output_tens, input_tens)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(grad, feed_dict={input_tens: np.zeros((1, n_features))})
```

Which fails with the following error

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value dense_7/bias
     [[Node: dense_7/bias/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@dense_7/bias"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](dense_7/bias)]]
```

(The stack trace is long and, I assume, not very informative, so I'm not adding it here).

Is my approach basically correct? Is there anything special I have to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your `keras` session in order to make it work:

```
import keras.backend as K

with K.get_session() as sess:
    sess.run(grad, feed_dict={input_tens: np.zeros((1, n_features))})
```

When you instantiate a new session - you don't have initialized variables from `keras` training.

Comment: I am a bit confused here: how do the gradients get calculated when no labels have been specified? How is the loss computed?