# Computing gradients of keras output with respect to the network inputs?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gradient, keras-layer

If i have a network in Keras with some input variables say x, y, z. How would i calculate the gradient of the outputs with respect to each of these inputs (x,y,z). I have been looking around and can't find a clear answer to this and haven't managed to work it out myself after messing around with tf.gradients for a while.
I have seen this question [Keras with TF backend: get gradient of outputs with respect to inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064178/keras-with-tf-backend-get-gradient-of-outputs-with-respect-to-inputs) 
but this is not clear at all to me and i don't understand what to do or how to implement it. Any help and simple example would be great, thanks.

EDIT:

Here is a concrete example of what i am looking for. 
Consider for example the function f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2.

```py
def function(x,y,z):
    return (x**2) + (y**2) + (z**2)

network = Sequential()
network.add(Dense(128, input_shape=3, activation='relu'))
network.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
network.add(Dense(1,activation='relu'))
```

If I trained the neural network on random examples of x,y,z and function values f(x,y,z) and approximated the function f(x,y,z), what i would like to do is to then use the network to return the gradient of the function with respect to each of the inputs individually. The gradient vector for this example would be given by 
f'(x,y,z) = 2x + 2y +2z. So once the network is trained, for a given input vector (x,y,z) i would like to not only approximate the function value but also its derivatives with respect to the inputs, for example, once the network has been trained if i provided say the input vector (1,2,3) to the network, i would not only like to get the network approximation for f(1,2,3) = 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 = 14, but i would like to get the approximation for the derivative of f(x,y,z) with respect to each of the individuals separately, so in this case i would want to approximate the partial derivative of f(x,y,z) with respect to x=1 which would of course be  2, and likewise for the partial derivative of f(x,y,z) with the respect to the other two inputs, which are 4 and 6 respectively. This is just a simple example of what i would like to do.

Comment: You need to be more clear, this question has been asked before, so you need to put a concrete problem, not just "I don't understand".

Comment: I have edited my question and added a concrete example of what i am looking for, i hope this helps clarify my position.